# Bootstrap "Navbar" css classes not working on my html page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap and I am following the Brad Hussey bootstrap tutorial for learning bootstrap.

The Navbar css classes are simply not loading for my webpage.
I have kept the index.html just outside the bootstrap css folder,am I not providing the correct path??what am i missing??
Little help would be highly appreciated...

attaching the image and the code snippet as well...

original.png is the what I want my page to look like.
my page.png is how my page is looking.

my developer console is also not showing any error,as can be seen in the image.

here's my code:
`

```
    <!--Mobile viewport optimized-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
    <body>
    <div class="container" id="main">
       <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class"container">
                <a class=""navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your Logo"></a>
           </div><!--end container-->
       </div><!--navbar-->
    </div><!--end container--></body>
```

`

Thanks,
Pranay

[image: Original.png]
[image: my page.png]

Comment: have you checked the source code..is that css is loading there..

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your problem could be here:

```
<a class=""navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your Logo"></a>
```

Modify it for:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your Logo"></a>
```

As you can see, there was a double quote, and also added a standar # link.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup needs to look like this to get the  desired result..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your Logo"></a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/127999

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class=""navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your Logo"></a>
```

Here ur syntax is wrong. you have put twice quotes in class. it should be

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your Logo"></a>
```

Please try this

Comment: Sorry, nothing like i copied its easily identified that syntax is wrong

Comment: Also the syntax on the links?